# Node.Js MYSQL felixge, callback when Delete

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Hi I would like to know if there is a way to check if a query was succesful and did delete some rows?

I would like something like:

```
connection.query('DELETE FROM table WHERE test=1,function(err,rows){
 if(rows.length>0){
func();
 }
});
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be:

```
connection.query('DELETE FROM table WHERE test=1', function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  if(result.affectedRows > 0){
      console.log('deleted ' + result.affectedRows + ' rows');
  }
});
```